# new Apache DocumentRoot but sometimes serves the old

Tags: apache-2.4

I have a Wordpress site installed on Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu). PHP is Php-fpm, 7.2.

I would like to change DocumentRoot from `/var/www/html/site1` to `/var/www/html/site2` but when I do, and after I restarted apache I sometimes get the site from `/var/www/html/site1` and sometimes from `/var/www/html/site2` ?

I also restarted the php-fpm daemon.

How can this be?

Comment: That sounds like a browser cache problem. Also look for absolute path declaration in your php app.

Comment: That came to my mind to, but it’s not the problem. If I append with ?blaha8281818 (something random) it’s not cached in browser and not on server, but I sometimes the old site and sometimes the new. On POST-request too.

Comment: and About path declaration in php, It’s a WordPress so it should not be a issue I think.

Comment: you might try to define different apache log files for both hosts and see if you actually still get requests for site1.log and for which urls to further explore . Or even more radical you could move the whole root directory of site1 to some other place (e.g. `mv /var/www/site1 ~/`) restart apache and see what happens.

Answer (score -1):

If you open a private/incognito session of your browser does the old version come up at all?

Are you sure there isn't any other Apache config file that's getting picked up?
Though I think that might result in a conflict anyway if there were.

Do the Apache logs on the server show that it's sometimes directing queries to the old folder?

Comment: Yes, incognito also get random responses. Sometimes from old,  sometimes from new. I have greped for the old folder but no matches are found in /etc/apache or its subfolders.. I haven’t seen anything about it in the logs but I will sure check again